# json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Invalid \escape

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, escaping, simplejson

I've tested if I can load the JSON.

---

First I import the built-in JSON module

```
Python 3.9.9 (tags/v3.9.9:ccb0e6a, Nov 15 2021, 18:08:50) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from json import loads
```

then I tryed all the methods below but all of none of it works.

```py
>>> jsondata = """{
...     "robloxtypes": {"generic": "generic", "uwp": "uwp"},
...     "cursorfolder": ".\\content\\KeyboardMouse"
... }"""
>>> jsondatax = loads(jsondata)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\json\__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\json\decoder.py", line 353, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Invalid \escape: line 3 column 23 (char 81)
```

```py
>>> jsondata = """{
...     "robloxtypes": {"generic": "generic", "uwp": "uwp"},
...     "cursorfolder": ".\content\KeyboardMouse"
... }"""
>>> jsondatax = loads(jsondata)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\json\__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\json\decoder.py", line 353, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Invalid \escape: line 3 column 23 (char 81)
```

```py
>>> jsondata = """{
...     "robloxtypes": {"generic": "generic", "uwp": "uwp"},
...     "cursorfolder": r".\content\KeyboardMouse"
... }"""
>>> jsondatax = loads(jsondata)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\json\__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 3 column 21 (char 79)
>>>
```

So I want to know what is wrong, and what should I do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you want to preserve the escaping you need to denote the string literal as a *raw string* using the prefix `r` or `R`:

```
jsondata = r"""{
    "robloxtypes": {"generic": "generic", "uwp": "uwp"},
    "cursorfolder": ".\\content\\KeyboardMouse"
}"""
```